# Rails problem in production mode, mysql database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, deployment, production-environment

App is running smoothly in development mode, but deploying it onto a managed server brings up the public/500.html page *("We're sorry, but something went wrong")*, seemingly when content queries the mysql database. Putting up static content works, puzzlingly dynamic content only works locally in dev.

*rake db:migrate* went properly, I've manually inserted a test entry into the mysql database.

Yet requesting the view results in 500 and the log gives

```
ActionView::Template::Error (NULL pointer given):
    10:  ...
    11:    <% @projects.each do |project| %>
    12:  ...
```

Server runs MySQL 5.1.54, Rails has mysql gem installed.
Any hints appreciated!

**edit:**

So I just started

`rails c production`

on the remote server and created an entry in my "Client" model:

`irb(main):003:0> c = Client.new
=> #<Client id: nil, name: nil, permalink: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):004:0> c.name = "realclient"
=> "realclient"
irb(main):005:0> c
=> #<Client id: nil, name: "realclient", permalink: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):006:0> c.save
=> true`

While all fields except for *name* are displayed empty in irb, the actual DB on the server show all repective fields okay:

`2  realclient  realclient  2011-04-22 13:59:12 2011-04-22 13:59:12`
(id, name, permalink, created, updated)

So bottom line: Active Record cannot receive values correctly from the DB that are actually there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

** **Solved** **

My hosting provider only allows use of their pre-installed mysql 2.7 gem. Any manual loading of a mysql gem in Gemfile results in Active Record errors – even loading an own 2.7 version on top. Sticking to the default gem on the managed server works.

Setting up a new database individually on the server could probably enable use of custom database gems. So while this was a very specific problem, maybe the answer helps somebody else working with rails on a managed server.

Answer (score 0):

When you ran `rake db:migrate` you probably did not have a `RAILS_ENV` set and so were still running in *development* environment.  Try running:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate
```

See if you get an error then, and if so you can re-run it with the `--trace` option for more detail.

You probably need to debug this issue on your `config/database.yml` - there'll be something missing or misconfigured in the *production* section (or maybe you haven't created the DB or something, I'm not familiar with that specific error message).

Comment: `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate` went normally, all tables have successfully been created. Therefore we could take the database.yml as correct? 
`--trace` shows no errors.
Just dropped the DB entirely and did a fresh migration. So, when no entries are present there, views render normally. As soon as the DB gets populated and there is indeed something to query views result in error 500. Do you have another idea on your mind? Thanks a lot!

Comment: In addition I set up another DB with MySQL 4.x instead of the previous 5 version, but error persists when populated.
Also I double checked the few bundled gems which are found OK.
Anybody knows how to read more information from Apache or passenger logs on the managed server? (Do not know how to get a hand on those) 
The messages from `tail -f` do not seem to help here.

Comment: I'm wondering what other differences there could be between your web server instance and your command line.  How is the server running your Rails app?  Perhaps the web server is using a different Ruby (and hence a different mysql gem)?

Comment: **Solved**
The hosting provider only allows use of their pre-installed mysql 2.7 gem. Any manual loading of mysql gems via Gemfile resulted in Active Record errors – even loading an own 2.7 version on top. Sticking to the default gem on the managed server works. Thanks a lot for your thoughts though, very much appreciated.